# Add users to a group upon purchase [check if a purchasable has a variant]

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I have a module to add a user to a group after a specific product type purchase. This was working fine, until I added [Events](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/events/features) to the mix. From what I understand, Events don't have variants so now I'm having issues.

Here is my code (it's probably very messy but it's worked so far):

```
Event::on(Order::class, Order::EVENT_AFTER_COMPLETE_ORDER, function (Event $event) {
  $order = $event->sender;
  $membersGroup = ["1"];
  $user = Craft::$app->getUsers()->getUserById($order->customer->userId);
  foreach ($order->lineItems as $item) {
    $purchasable = $item->getPurchasable();
    $variant = $purchasable->getProduct();
    $productType = $variant->getType();
    if ($productType->id == "3") {
      foreach ($user->getGroups() as $group) {
        array_push($membersGroup, $group->id);
      }
      Craft::$app->users->assignUserToGroups($order->customer->userId, $membersGroup);
    }
  }
});
```

As it stands, a regular Commerce product will process without issue. Purchasing an Event ticket will process ok, but the user is taken back to the payment page.

As soon as I comment out `$variant = $purchasable->getProduct();` and change `$productType = $variant->getType();` to `$productType = $purchasable->getType();`, the opposite happens (ticket is successful, regular product is not.)

Does any one have any thoughts on how I could make this work in both scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

I've not used Events, but I would presume they extend the Purchasable class as per https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/3.x/extend/purchasable-types.html

Seems like therefore you could use PHP's `instanceof` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php) to check the type of

`$purchasable = $item->getPurchasable();`

...and create two paths from there depending on what type of line item you're dealing with one each occasion.